# Revisions list should tell which mod moved comments to chat

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, revisions-list, automatic-comments

When a mod moves comments to chat, an entry "Mod Moved Comments To Chat" appears in the edit history (revisions list) of a question/answer ([Example](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/424510/revisions)).

It would be more useful, in my view, if this entry included the name of the mod who did it ("Comments Moved To Chat By $(MODERATORNAME)").

Currently most moderator actions leave a trace that specifies who did it and when (for instance, protecting questions, closing questions 'by authority', deleting them...), and this is an exception. Is there a reason why it works this way? If no, can this be changed?

Answer (score 7):

When a moderator moves comments to chat, a comment is automatically posted by that user linking to that chat room.

[image]

This comment shows which moderator performed the action, and when.

Comment: Can this comment be deleted or edited?

Comment: Deleted. yes. but that kinda defeats the purpose of moving to chat. We cannot edit *who* posted it, but what is posted. I'd note though, if you're going to complain its moved to chat, you should remember the alternative is a overloaded comment thread that the powers that be want to discourage, *or* deletion. Moving to chat is a *good* thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree with you, moving comments to chat is a *good* thing 99.9% of the time.

Comment: You should also note that it's possible for moderators to redact the revision history of a post (though this requires two moderators iirc) and that _every_ moderator action (including some you've never heard of) is permanently logged in a private but mod / cm-accessible area.